# jQuery: check length for tr's inside

Tags: jquery

I have this I need to rewrite:

```
if( $('tr.notification:visible').length == 0 ) {
```

So it checks if the length is == 0 of the table it is inside. I do not want to specify the table´s id, as I want this to work on all the tables.

$(this) is class .removeAction that is inside the table, and inside a tr.

I used .notification because all the tr´s in the table had the class notification. But I have more tables, with tr´s that has the class .notification, so this cannot be used, otherwise it would work fine.

So the table, the .removeAction is inside, is the length==0, then alert('yes')

How can I do that?

Comment: So you have a table that has a class `removeAction`, is that on the table or somewhere within it? And you want the `<tr>` from that, which has the `notification` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( $(this).closest('table').find('tr.notification:visible').length == 0 ) {
```